# Send cookies via HttpRequest in PHP along with request

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, asterisk

I've got a PBX server (Asterisk 1.8), and I'm able to manage calls via some GET variables in a request. My issue is that I need to first login to the server. Once I've done so I want to save a cookie, and then send it along for verification along with my next requestion.

I have code that currently works using cURL:

```
public function authenticate(){
    $temp_dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $ckfile = tempnam($temp_dir, "ast");

    $auth_url = $this->ast_link."?action=login&username=asterisk_http&secret=*****";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $auth_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $this->auth_cookie = $ckfile;
    return $ckfile;
}
//$call contains id, patcode, phone_number, call_type
public function makeCall($overload, $call, $exten, $user = NULL){
    set_time_limit(0);

    if(!$this->auth_cookie) $this->authenticate();
            //http://blah.server/asterisk/rawman?action=originate&channel=$somechannel
    $call_url = $this->generateCallUrl($overload, $call, $exten, $user);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->auth_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Unfortunately cURL waits for a response from the server, which only happens at the end of a call. Because of this I'm unable to make multiple calls simultaneously.

How could I use HttpRequest in PHP to send a cookie along with the request in the same way that cURL does? I'm a little unfamilliar with the networking mechanics behind this, so forgive me for my ignorance on this.

TL;DR: How to send cookie along with HttpRequest

Comment: In `HttpRequest` you can use `enableCookies` method to accept and send cookies, however this will work not if you want to save the cookies and use them in another call to the script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you question is concerned on "How to send cookie along with HttpRequest" I think I might be able to help because I have just solved a similar problem.

First thing's first, whenever you want to know what is going on at the network level i.e what type of requests are coming and what type are being sent, do look for Network Tab in the Chorme Console. Alternatively you can download and install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) which will help you monitor incoming and outgoing requests (These tips will really help you in your next project).

And as for setting the cookies via HTTP Header just use the following php code.

```
header('Set-Cookie: CookieName='.$content);
```

Here Cookie Name is the name of any session cookie i.e JSESSIONID etc and the content is the related key that has to be shouted every time a client needs to get authenticated.

**I hope this information will help you and other developers :)**

Comment: I think he was looking for sending cookies in a request, thus emulating browser behaviour and not setting cookies in a response.

Comment: Ya that is what I was trying to explain. Sending cookies along with the request you make with JavaScript. And that is the main reason you might want to see the header of these requests in FireBug. Its a great plugin that comes with both chrome and Firefox.